# Given an average and a maximum, how determine the minimum range

Tags: descriptive-statistics, mean

Suppose that we have $k$ non-negative values. We know the average $A \in \mathbb{N}$ of these values and we know that the maximum value is $M$ (not necessarily $\in \mathbb{N}$) we don't know the remaining $k-1$ values. How to determine the smallest possible minimum $m$ such that $$\frac{m+M+\textrm{other_values(unknown)}}{k}=A$$.

We can assume that $M > A$ since $M=A$ if and only if all of the other values are equal and $m=M$. Note that the assumptions $M> A$, $m <A$ are equivalent.

Comment: Did you try working with a small example? Suppose A=100, k=10, and M=105. So there are 10 numbers, the largest of which is 105, and their average is 100. How small can the minimum of these numbers be? Convince yourself that it can't be arbitrarily low, and try to work from there.

Comment: Yes I am convinced that it can be arbitrarily low.
Here is a try : 
$\frac{m+M+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-2} a_i}{k} = A$, thus $m = KA - M - \sum_{i=1}^{k-2} a_i $. Then, $m$ is minimal when the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{k-2} a_i$ is maximal, so should we pick this sum as $(k-2) \times M$ to be maximal. The lowest possible value of $m$ is then $kA - (k-1)M$ ?

Comment: yes, that's precisely it.